# sbt unable to build play framework app

Tags: playframework, sbt

I get this error when trying to build my pay framework app with sbt.

I followed all of the steps according to the play framework site (setting up build.sbt plugins.sbt and build.properties).

I have tried everything I can think of however I have limited knowledge. I've ensured all proxy settings were set, reinstalled my jdk and tried using both the 'activator new' and 'sbt' methods.

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.x ...
[error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building 
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target 
url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.3.x/sbt-plugin-2.3.x.pom
```

The error mentions something to do with certification, what does this mean?

Googling around mentions it refering to a 'cacerts' file in %JAVA_HOME%/lib/security (which mine did not contain), I tried copying the 'cacerts' file from another java installation I have on my computer and that didn't do anything (however I was completely guessing here haha).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the security warning is possibly misleading based on my own experiences.

Are you behind a corporate network and if so, have you tried configuring your proxy settings for Play?

Play attempts to connect to the Typesafe repository to check for updates and dependencies during a build and if it cannot connect you will get a network error - I got the same errors as you but it was a network error not a security one - its just that the certificate issue is the first failure to be reported.

Try running your build using a direct internet connection if you can as a test (assuming you are on corporate network). If that fixes it you just need to configure your network proxy settings in your build (assuming any internet policies configured on the proxy don't also cause any issues).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the response. I am behind a corporate proxy, and have added my proxy settings everywhere that I could think might affect it. I've provided proxy details in the activatorconfig.txt file in .activator and .activator/1.3.5 and the maven config file. I also tried providing proxy details in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. I've run out of ideas :S. Is there somewhere else I need to put them? You mentioned Play, is there a specific play config file? I'm sure that the proxy settings I have provided are correct as they are working with my node.js install and npm.

Comment: I had problems with getting activatorconfig working but managed to get HTTP_PROXY=http://<host>:<port> working on a mac. If that does not work then you might try asking for help from the Google Play group which is where the Typesafe guys seem to provide the most help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, still no luck with the proxy settings =_=, so frustrating !! I will try the google group as you said =]

Comment: Yes, it is a bit frustrating since Im sure it is a common problem with Play users on corporate networks and there isn't a great deal of information available. BTW - as an aside, you can work with Play offline (removes the update check) - but of course it is only any good once you have pulled all your dependencies down for a successful build. see - http://www.poornerd.com/2013/05/29/play-framework-tip-for-developing-offline/